# Bind dependency Property to Child Element in Code behind

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I basically got a ContentControl that has Border as content witch also has TextBlock as content. What i want is that e.g. the Foreground Brush of the TextBlock is bound to a dependency property of the parent ContentControl... I am stuck right here i don't know how to solve this.

```
public class NumberRollItem : ContentControl
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int AnimationIndex { get; set; }

    public Brush ItemForeground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ItemForegroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemForegroundProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemForegroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemForeground", typeof(Brush), typeof(NumberRollItem), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)));        
    public Brush ItemBackground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ItemBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(NumberRollItem), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)));
    public double ItemFontSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ItemFontSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemFontSizeProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemFontSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemFontSize", typeof(double), typeof(NumberRollItem), new PropertyMetadata(45d));



    public NumberRollItem(char c, int index)
    {
        this.Index = index;
        string text = ""; text += c;

        HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        Content = new Border()
        {
            Background = ItemBackground, // Background bound to ItemBackground but how??
            HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
            Child = new TextBlock()
            {
                FontSize = 45,
                Text = text,
                Foreground = ItemForeground,
            },
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for WP**

Well if you're doing everything via code, you can create the Binding in code too,

Something like:

```
public NumberRollItem(char c, int index)
{
  this.Index = index;
  string text = ""; text += c;

  // Giving This control a Name to later use for Binding
  string thisControlName = "NumberItem";

  Name = thisControlName;

  HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
  var tBlock = new TextBlock()
  {
    FontSize = 45,
    Text = text
  };
  var binding = new Binding
  {
    ElementName = thisControlName,
    Path = new PropertyPath("ItemForeground")
  };
  tBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, binding);
  Content = new Border()
  {
    Background = ItemBackground,
    HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
    VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
    Child = tBlock,
  };
}
```

What you're doing with this code is:

In the constructor of `NumberRollItem` you create a `Binding` with `ElementName` pointing to `NumberRollItem` class and assign the Binding to the `TextBlock.ForegroundProperty`. This will thus have them bound to allow for any future changes to `ItemForeground` to affect the `TextBlock.Foreground` as well.

Not sure why you've taken this approach and not the xaml `Style` route but whatever works for ya :)

Comment: Actually there is no RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor in Windows-Phone but thanks anyway.

Comment: @ElMarchewko oh I forgot this was for WP. I've updated the answer to work for Windows phone. Basically Just switch the `RelativeSource` binding to a simple Binding with `ElementName` as shown in the updated answer. I've checked it to work fine on the emulator.